# Spring MVC image uploading and ImageIO conversion fails on Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, javax.imageio

I'm working on a website where users can upload images.

I created a Spring controller for this. When the user uploads the image I want to convert it to PNG then upload it to an AWS S3 folder. Everything works fine on Windows however the PNG conversion fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!` on Linux.

Both Windows and Linux have the same Oracle JDK installed with java version of 1.8.0_161.

These are the available image readers on the server:

```
Oracle Corporation | 0.5 | Standard JPEG Image Reader
Oracle Corporation | 1.0 | Standard BMP Image Reader
Oracle Corporation | 1.0 | Standard WBMP Image Reader
Oracle Corporation | 1.0 | Standard GIF image reader
Oracle Corporation | 1.0 | Standard PNG image reader
```

I tested it with JPG, PNG and GIF files.  All of them were failing.

The exact exception is:

```
018-04-05 06:23:57.414 ERROR 31434 --- [p-nio-80-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1592)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1578)
        at com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.service.logo.RestaurantLogoUploader.convertImageToPng(RestaurantLogoUploader.java:69)
```

**When I disable the PNG conversion and only upload the raw image to S3 then the size of the image that's uploaded from Linux is slightly bigger (around +30%). The correct image is obviously the one uploaded from Windows.**

I post all of the related code because I'm not exactly sure witch step causes the problem.

This is my controller:

```
package com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.view.controller;

import com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.domain.RestaurantEntry;
import com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.service.RestaurantEntryFactory;
import com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.service.logo.RestaurantLogoUploader;
import com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.view.controller.exception.UnauthorizedAccessException;
import com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.view.service.file.FileConverter;
import com.morethanheroic.user.domain.UserEntity;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restaurant/{restaurantId}/logo")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestaurantLogoUploadController {

    private final RestaurantEntryFactory restaurantEntryFactory;
    private final RestaurantLogoUploader restaurantLogoUploader;
    private final FileConverter fileConverter;

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public void uploadFile(final UserEntity userEntity, @PathVariable final int restaurantId,
                           @RequestPart("logo") final MultipartFile logo) {
        final RestaurantEntry restaurantEntry = restaurantEntryFactory.getRestaurant(restaurantId);

        if (!restaurantEntry.isOwner(userEntity)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }

        restaurantLogoUploader.uploadLogo(restaurantEntry, fileConverter.convertMultiPartToFile(logo));
    }
}
```

The file converter:

```
package com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.view.service.file;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class FileConverter {

    public File convertMultiPartToFile(final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        final File result = new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

        try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(result)) {
            fos.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Unable to convert MultiPart to File!", e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is the actual image uploader where the conversion happens.

```
package com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.service.logo;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.domain.RestaurantEntry;
import com.morethanheroic.restaurantapp.restaurant.service.logo.configuration.RestaurantLogoProperties;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class RestaurantLogoUploader {

    private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;
    private final RestaurantLogoProperties restaurantLogoProperties;
    private final RestaurantLogoNameFactory restaurantLogoNameFactory;

    public RestaurantLogoUploader(@Qualifier("amazonLogoUploaderS3Client") final AmazonS3 amazonS3,
                                  final RestaurantLogoProperties restaurantLogoProperties,
                                  final RestaurantLogoNameFactory restaurantLogoNameFactory) {
        this.amazonS3 = amazonS3;
        this.restaurantLogoProperties = restaurantLogoProperties;
        this.restaurantLogoNameFactory = restaurantLogoNameFactory;
    }

    public void uploadLogo(final RestaurantEntry restaurant, final File restaurantLogo) {
        final String logoName = restaurantLogoNameFactory.buildName(restaurant);

        amazonS3.putObject(restaurantLogoProperties.getBucketName(), logoName, convertImageToPng(restaurantLogo));
    }

    private File convertImageToPng(final File inputFile) {
        log.info("Converting file " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to png.");

        try {
            final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
            final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", byteArrayOut);

            final byte[] resultingBytes = byteArrayOut.toByteArray();

            final File result = new File(inputFile.getName());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(result);
            fos.write(resultingBytes);
            fos.close();

            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to convert image.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the log say ("Converting file ... to png."). [ImageIO.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.InputStream-) evidently returned null, as it may do. Maybe the file name is not okay.

Comment: Usually there is no need to deal with `File`s in a servlet environment. I would usually do this: `InputStream is = multipartFile.getInputStream(); BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is); ImageIO.write(bi, "png", ...);`.

Comment: I would start looking at the files after uploading to the Linux server (perhaps attach one that fails). If `ImageIO.read` returns `null`, then the file is not recognized. Your image conversion code looks mostly good (except the writing to byte array, then writing to file, you could write to file directly).

Comment: I added some more info to the post. "When I disable the PNG conversion and only upload the raw image to S3 then the size of the image that's uploaded from Linux is slightly bigger (around +30%). The correct image is obviously the one uploaded from Windows."

Comment: @JoopEggen Something like "Converting file /root/2c93ff3d290f9c6d54c58c849990f16d.png to png." The file is actually there and exists.

Comment: @manish That looks much cleaner!

Comment: `AmazonS3` also provides methods that accept streams, so intermediate saving to files can be avoided altogether.

Comment: @manish Spring is not going to save the file either way?

Comment: Handling of multipart requests is entirely up to the servlet container - it may or may not save files uploaded in multipart requests to a disk. Spring's `MultipartFile` abstraction simply makes it easy to read file data; it too does not guarantee or require that the uploaded file will be available on a disk. JavaDoc comments for that class provide more details.

Comment: @manish Thank a lot! I reworked my solution and it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The web app should not be run as `root` (administrator rights) so access to the **/root** directory is not allowed. Configure the upload directory elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. I'll iron that mistake out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by AWS API Gateway. After listing 'multipart/form-data' as a Binary Media Type everything worked as expected.